# multiple initializations in for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a function to find the average of numbers at first i wrote code as

```
double CPPLib::average_of_numbers(std::vector<int> &numbers){
    double result = -1;
    if(numbers.size() != 0)
    {
        result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i< int(numbers.size());i++)
        {
            result += numbers[i];
            std::cout << result << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
        result = result/numbers.size();
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

for the input {1,2,3,4,5} the above code works fine and prints
1
3
6
10
15
15
3
3
.but when i tried to include the result = 0 in "for" loop initialization i am getting result as -1 after for loop.as shown in the code

```
double CPPLib::average_of_numbers(std::vector<int> &numbers){
    double result = -1;
    if(numbers.size() != 0)
    {
        
        for(int i=0,result = 0;i< int(numbers.size());i++)
        {
            result += numbers[i];
            std::cout << result << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
        result = result/numbers.size();
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

result is displayed as
1
3
6
10
15
**-1**
-0.2
-0.2
can you please let me know the reason for this.
Thank you so much.

Comment: `return (numbers.empty() ? -1. : (std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.) / numbers.size());`.

Comment: Like everywhere else `int i=0,result = 0` declares two `int` variables. It's not one declaration with initializer and one assignment, separated by the comma operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, you've actually declared two separate variables called `result`.  The first is here at the top of your function.

```
double result = -1;
```

The other is here:

```
    for(int i=0,result = 0;i< int(numbers.size());i++)
```

You've declared both a temporary **int** named `result` (in addition to `i`) who's lifetime and scope is within the for-loop. It overrides the outer `result` declared earlier.  When the for-loop exits, references to `result` are back to the original variable declared earlier.

Easiest fix is to do what you were doing in your first example. Explicitly set `result=0` outside the loop.